# Data not being inserted into database from form, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following 2 files and a database that is running in the background. When ever I submit the form. The data is not being inserted into the database. It connects to my database successfully but it does not insert:

update.html

```
 <html> 
 <head><title>Test Page</title></head> 
 <body> 
 <h2>Data Collection</h2><p> 
 <form action="update.php" method="post"> 
 <table> 
 <tr><td>id</td><td><input type="text" name="id" /></td></tr> 
 <tr><td>title</td><td><input type="text" name="title" /></td></tr> 
 <tr><td>name</td><td><input type="text" name="name" /></td></tr> 
 <tr><td>hello</td><td><input type="text" name="hello" /></td></tr> 
 <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" /></td></tr> 
 </table> 
 </form> 
 </body> 
 </html>
```

update.php

```
 <?php

    $GLOBALS['title'];
    $GLOBALS['id'];
    $GLOBALS['name']; 
    $GLOBALS['hello'];

    $hostname="localhost:3036";
    $username="root";
    $password="";

    $con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
      or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

    // Check connection
    if (mysql_error())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error();
      }

    mysql_select_db('website');


    $sql="INSERT INTO articles (id, title, name, hello)
        VALUES('$id','$title','$name','$hello')";

    mysql_close($con);

    echo "test";
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Note: Mysql functions are deprecated and can cause security issues.  Use PDO or mysqli instead! Also make sure that you sanitize your database inputs :)

Comment: Talk about vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: `'$id','$title','$name','$hello'` are not set

Comment: I see where you are setting the SQL command to a string but I don't see where you are executing it. Could that be it?

Comment: and I don't see where you are executing the query, you should use: mysql_query($sql). (Althought you should not use mysql_* functions anymore.

Comment: If you combine the 2 answers it might work for you...

Comment: But, you should really switch to PDO (think it's the best) and learn how to do prepared statements to prevent SQL injection. Redo, do right.

Answer (score 1):

You are not executing the query at all and as correctly stated in the comments, you weren't setting the variables correctly;

change your code to match:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$hello = $_POST['hello'];

$hostname="localhost:3036";
$username="root";
$password="";

$con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

// Check connection
if (mysql_error())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error();
  }

mysql_select_db('website');

$sql="INSERT INTO articles (id, title, name, hello)
    VALUES('$id','$title','$name','$hello')";

mysql_query ( $sql, $con);

mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:
Note: i just ignore your deprecated msqyl function

```
<?php

$hostname="localhost:3036";
$username="root";
$password="";

$title = $_POST['title'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$hello = $_POST['hello'];

$con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

// Check connection
if (mysql_error())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error();
  }

mysql_select_db('website');


$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles (id, title, name, hello)
    VALUES('$id','$title','$name','$hello')") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close($con);

echo "test";
```

Answer (score 0):

First you are not defining the variables that are inserting. '$id','$title','$name','$hello'. 
Define previous to insert,  when the $_POST is accepted,  use

```
else {$id'= $_POST['id'];}
```

Second. and more important,  don't ever use this code which by the way is old, deprecated and very unhealthy.  It's prone to `SQL INJECTION`. 
Instead use `PDO`,  and sanitize user submitted values. 
Also avoid use of  `$GLOBALS`,  the same,  old, deprecated, unsafe.

Please refer to [PHP sanitize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) which explains how to clean your user submitted data. Check this:

```
 $id=filter_var($_POST['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```